# Datepicker does not work after hosting

Tags: asp.net-core

I have created a simple web app in visual studio 2017 and I'm hosting it on a debian server with NET. Core CLI tools.
My web app works just fine after hosting, except for the datepicker i put in a date form field.
It works fine when testing it in VS with IIS Express.

[When testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0i7uL.png)

But, after hosting it on the debian server the datepicker just does not appear. No errors.

[After hosting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UmVj.png)

Anyone knows how to fix this ?

Comment: Check this script.

Comment: Using bootstrap-datepicker. Top choice for datepicker in Bower. Can't find out why it works when testing, but not after hosting

Answer (score 0):

Okay i figured it out.

I put reference to the script under `<environment names="Staging,Production">` in the layout file and it works now. Previously i had it under `<environment names="Development">`